# Open Graph Actions for built in Objects

Tags: facebook, object, action, facebook-opengraph

i was wondering which actions match the built in objects:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/objects/builtin/

E.g. which action belongs to the object blog?

Below is is a list of build-in objects and connected build-in actions

- **Blog** (???)
- **Book** (???)
- **Website** (???)
- **External Profile** (???)
- Movie (viedo.watches)
- TV Episode (viedo.watches)
- TV Show (viedo.watches)
- Video (viedo.watches)
- Article (news.reads)

Answer (score 1):

I know that [built in action](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/builtin/) is quite limiting but you can publish and manage your own action. Look at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/

Comment: This is true, but you are not permitted to add your own Action Type with the same name as a built-in one. For example, if you try submitting an action called `Read` for the built-in object `Blog` or even your own custom object, Facebook will reject your request. You can't `clean windows` with a `Blog`, you want to `read` it. If there is a way round this, I am yet to find it.